# $S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ is the smallest $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal of $A$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification

The question is in A&D exercise 4.11 and I asked this in the previous post but I changed the question.
I want to show

> If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal of a ring $A$, show that $S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ is the smallest $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal.

Notation: $S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)=\text{Ker}(A\to A_{\mathfrak{p}})$.

I found some proof about this problem: Since $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal, $r(S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)) = \mathfrak{p}$. Next, if $xy\in S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ then there is $n>0$ such that $x^ny^n\in\mathfrak{p}$. If $x\notin S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$, then $x^n\notin\mathfrak{p}$ for all $n$ so that $y^n\in\mathfrak{p}$. Hence, there is $m>0$ such that $y^{nm}\in S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$.

In the proof, they said 'If $x\notin S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ then $x^n\notin \mathfrak{p}$ for all $n$'. I don't understand why this is true. Could you explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution: Suppose that $xy\in S_{\mathfrak p}(0)$. We need to show that either $x\in S_{\mathfrak p}(0)$ or $y^n\in S_{\mathfrak p}(0)$ for some $n>0$. Assume that $y\notin \mathfrak p=r(S_{\mathfrak p}(0))$, that is, $y^n\notin S_{\mathfrak p}(0)$ for all $n>0$. Since $xy$ is in $S_{\mathfrak p}(0)=\ker(A\to A_{\mathfrak p})$, we can find some $s\notin \mathfrak p$ such that $$sxy=0=(sy)x.$$ As $y\notin \mathfrak p$, we see that $sy\notin\mathfrak p$, hence we obtain $x\in \ker(A\to A_{\mathfrak p})=S_{\mathfrak p}(0)$.